# Gulp takes too much time to execute - long write gulp-ssh function

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

After moving to Gulp 4 my sftp-write function from gulp-ssh takes over 16s, sometimes its even 20s. In Gulp 3 it was much below 1s.

So I am beginner in Gulp, I had been using Gulp 3 for two years and it worked awesome. What I am using is gulp-sass and gulp-ssh. My scss files are compiling and then they go straight to the server via SSH.

Everything works - files are compiled and they are going to the server, but it takes too much time. In gulp 3 it was really faster. When I moved to Gulp4 I used gulp.series as everyone showed me in the internet and it worked, but I can't wait almost 20s to execute, it's horrible.

be gentle, I'm aware that my code maybe is broken, so I just need help :)

So I get this:

```
[09:48:39] Finished 'sftp-write-css-colors' after 19 s
[09:48:39] Finished 'sftp-write-css-footer' after 20 s
[09:48:39] Finished 'sftp-write-css-mixins' after 20 s
[09:48:39] Finished 'sftp-write-css-forms' after 20 s
[09:48:40] Finished 'sftp-write-css-fonts' after 20 s
[09:48:40] Finished 'sftp-write-css-header' after 20 s
[09:48:40] Finished 'sftp-write-css' after 20 s
[09:48:40] Finished 'sftp-write-css-buttons' after 21 s
[09:48:40] Finished 'sftp-write-css-main-styles' after 21 s
[09:48:41] Finished 'sftp-write-sass-main-styles' after 21 s
```

and my code looks like this:
( '---' are things that I don't want to share like password)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var fs = require('fs');
var GulpSSH = require('gulp-ssh');

var config = {
  host: '---',
  port: 22,
  username: '---',
  passphrase: '---',
  privateKey: fs.readFileSync('---.ssh/id_rsa')
}
var gulpSSH = new GulpSSH({
  ignoreErrors: false,
  sshConfig: config
})
gulp.task('exec', function () {
  return gulpSSH
    .exec(['uptime', 'ls -a', 'pwd'], {filePath: 'commands.log'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('logs'))
})

// write styles-sass
gulp.task('sftp-write-sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('sass/styles-sass.scss')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/sass/styles-sass.scss'))
})
gulp.task('sftp-write-css', function () {
  return gulp.src('css/styles-sass.css')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/css/styles-sass.css'))
})

// write colors 
gulp.task('sftp-write-sass-colors', function () {
  return gulp.src('sass/colors.scss')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/sass/colors.scss'))
})
gulp.task('sftp-write-css-colors', function () {
  return gulp.src('css/colors.css')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/css/colors.css'))
})

// write buttons
gulp.task('sftp-write-sass-buttons', function () {
  return gulp.src('sass/buttons.scss')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/sass/buttons.scss'))
})
gulp.task('sftp-write-css-buttons', function () {
  return gulp.src('css/buttons.css')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/css/buttons.css'))
})

// write fonts
gulp.task('sftp-write-sass-fonts', function () {
  return gulp.src('sass/fonts.scss')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/sass/fonts.scss'))
})
gulp.task('sftp-write-css-fonts', function () {
  return gulp.src('css/fonts.css')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/css/fonts.css'))
})

// write forms
gulp.task('sftp-write-sass-forms', function () {
  return gulp.src('sass/forms.scss')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/sass/forms.scss'))
})
gulp.task('sftp-write-css-forms', function () {
  return gulp.src('css/forms.css')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/css/forms.css'))
})

// write main-styles
gulp.task('sftp-write-sass-main-styles', function () {
  return gulp.src('sass/main-styles.scss')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/sass/main-styles.scss'))
})
gulp.task('sftp-write-css-main-styles', function () {
  return gulp.src('css/main-styles.css')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/css/main-styles.css'))
})

// write mixins
gulp.task('sftp-write-sass-mixins', function () {
  return gulp.src('sass/mixins.scss')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/sass/mixins.scss'))
})
gulp.task('sftp-write-css-mixins', function () {
  return gulp.src('css/mixins.css')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/css/mixins.css'))
})

// write header
gulp.task('sftp-write-sass-header', function () {
  return gulp.src('sass/header.scss')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/sass/header.scss'))
})
gulp.task('sftp-write-css-header', function () {
  return gulp.src('css/header.css')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/css/header.css'))
})

// write footer
gulp.task('sftp-write-sass-footer', function () {
  return gulp.src('sass/footer.scss')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/sass/footer.scss'))
})
gulp.task('sftp-write-css-footer', function () {
  return gulp.src('css/footer.css')
    .pipe(gulpSSH.sftp('write', '/css/footer.css'))
})

gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
});
gulp.task('verby-sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('verby/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('verby/css'))
});
gulp.task('signature-sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('sass/signature-sass.scss')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass')); 

  gulp.watch('sass/main-styles.scss', gulp.series('sftp-write-sass-main-styles'));
  gulp.watch('css/main-styles.css', gulp.series('sftp-write-css-main-styles'));

  gulp.watch('sass/styles-sass.scss', gulp.series('sftp-write-sass'));
  gulp.watch('css/styles-sass.css', gulp.series('sftp-write-css'));

  gulp.watch('sass/colors.scss', gulp.series('sftp-write-sass-colors'));
  gulp.watch('css/colors.css', gulp.series('sftp-write-css-colors'));

  gulp.watch('sass/buttons.scss', gulp.series('sftp-write-sass-buttons'));
  gulp.watch('css/buttons.css', gulp.series('sftp-write-css-buttons'));

  gulp.watch('sass/fonts.scss', gulp.series('sftp-write-sass-fonts'));
  gulp.watch('css/fonts.css', gulp.series('sftp-write-css-fonts'));

  gulp.watch('sass/forms.scss', gulp.series('sftp-write-sass-forms'));
  gulp.watch('css/forms.css', gulp.series('sftp-write-css-forms'));

  gulp.watch('sass/header.scss', gulp.series('sftp-write-sass-header'));
  gulp.watch('css/header.css', gulp.series('sftp-write-css-header'));

  gulp.watch('sass/footer.scss', gulp.series('sftp-write-sass-footer'));
  gulp.watch('css/footer.css', gulp.series('sftp-write-css-footer'));

  gulp.watch('sass/mixins.scss', gulp.series('sftp-write-sass-mixins'));
  gulp.watch('css/mixins.css', gulp.series('sftp-write-css-mixins'));

  gulp.watch('verby/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.series('verby-sass'));

  gulp.watch('sass/signature-sass.scss', gulp.series('signature-sass'));

});
```